# How can I draw this shape in xaml WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have to draw this shape in XAML. How can I draw this?

[image: shape]

I tried this and this is OK but can't split two color

```
      <Path Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red">
                                            <Path.Data>
                                                <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="5,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
                                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0 5 80" />
                                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="5,0 5 80" />
                                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="5,80" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
                                                </GeometryGroup>
                                            </Path.Data>
                                        </Path>
```

Comment: With two Path elements. What have you tried?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-combined-geometry

Comment: @Clemens , I edited my question and add my Try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use two Paths in a Canvas like these:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Fill="Yellow" Data="M0,0 A5,5 0 0 0 5,5 L5,75 A5,5 0 0 0 0,80Z"/>
    <Path Fill="Red" Data="M5,5 A 5,5 0 0 0 10,0 L10,80 A5,5 0 0 0 5,75Z"/>
</Canvas>
```

For details, see [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. Perhaps the easiest one would be to create a `Grid` with two `Ellipse` elements that overlay the yellow and red parts:

```
<Grid Width="50" Height="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Yellow" />
    <Grid Background="Red" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-25,0,0" />
    <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-25" />
</Grid>
```

[image]